# Connecting Backbone.js with CouchDB when hosting in Apache or IIS

Tags: backbone.js, couchdb

I'm having trouble understanding how to connect Backbone.js with CouchDB cleanly if I am to serve the html and js files from Apache web server or IIS (not from node.js or couchApp).

Should I use a backbone.js CouchDB extension to abstract the requests? If so which ?

Should I connect Backbone.js connect directly to the CouchDB RESTful interface or should I use 
an intermediate PHP layer (because I am familiar with PHP but and not Java or other server side setups) ? If so which ?

What is the best way to deal with the 'same origin policy' preventing me from interacting with the database ?

Basically I want a tidy way using backbone.js to `GET` json documents from a number of `collections` by id, an array of ids, or all ids.
Also from a second admin web interface I need to be able to update, create, and delete by `id`

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need any extension to work with CouchDB.

The main thing you need to do is set [idAttribute](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-idAttribute) to `_id` in all your model.

Also, I would advise you to put an intermediate layer between CouchDB and your client. Unless your use-case is very simple, you'll quickly want to transform your documents before sending them to your client. You can do that with PHP, Express and use [CouchApp](http://couchapp.org/page/what-is-couchapp) if you want to stick close to CouchDB.

If you want to bypass SOP cleanly, take a look at [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), which is now supported by most browsers.

I'm not familiar with PHP, but here's how I do it with [Express](http://expressjs.com) and [felix-couchdb](https://github.com/felixge/node-couchdb):

```
var couchdb = require('felix-couchdb'),
    client = couchdb.createClient(config.port, config.host),
    myDb = client.db('my_db');

// (... express boilerplate)
app.get('/resource/:resource_id', function (req, res) {
  myDb.getDoc(req.params.resource_id, function (err, doc) {
    if(err)
      return res.send(err);

    res.send(doc);
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you recommend any libraries that essentially only need installation and configuration ? particularly for PHP but also (node/express) ?

Answer (score 0):

I have had very good luck with https://cloudant.com/blog/backbone-and-cloudant/